# hector slam configuration

Tags: hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
i have kinect 1, i conver it to laser_scan and all is ok.
i want to make hector SLAM, i install it with:

```
git clone https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam.git
```

now, i don't know how to configure it with rviz although i follow this tutorial [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot)

can you show me how to configure it please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235118/hector-slam-configuration/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of getting the source code and building it by yourself, you can download the binaries i.e. hector_slam package itself for your ROS distribution. You can use command

> sudo apt-get install ros-your_ros_dist_name-hector-slam

for eg. in case of ros indigo you can use command

> sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-hector-slam

this will download and install all the necessary packages for hector slam.

---

Originally posted by [gp](https://answers.ros.org/users/26916/gp/) with karma: 166 on 2016-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-05-27**:
yes and after installation, i must modify something?
i have laser scan data and odometry data

**Comment by [gp](https://answers.ros.org/users/26916/gp/) on 2016-05-27**:
then follow this tutorial [setting your robot](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot). For example you can check this project [hector_slam_example](https://github.com/DaikiMaekawa/hector_slam_example/tree/master). In hector_hokuyo.launch file, replace hokuyo part by kinect.

**Comment by [gp](https://answers.ros.org/users/26916/gp/) on 2016-05-27**:
If you just want to check hector slam you can follow this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/MappingUsingLoggedData). After installing binaries you don't need to modify anything. You can straightaway use it.

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-05-27**:
ok thanks i will  try this

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-05-27**:
thank you it works well